# Run in background two command lines one after the end of the other

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script, I have two command lines where the second must start after the first finishes(the second command need some files which will be generated by the first command) and i want to run the two commands in background. How can i do that please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(command1 ; command2) &
```

Here's relevant doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Comment: `(command1 && command2) &` is probably more robust since it will not run `command2` if  `command1` fails.